# Restore default from python 2.7 to python 2.6

Tags: python, linux, centos

Recently I installed Python 2.7 on Centos machine which had default Python2.6, which changed default to python2.7 (/usr/local/bin/python). Now things started breaking, so I need to switch back default to python2.6 (/usr/bin/python) for all users, keeping python2.6 and python2.7 installed on system. How do I do this ?

Please Help..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you installed python 2.7 manually into `/usr/local` then your default path is to blame for this problem.

`/usr/local/bin` usually proceeds `/usr/bin` in the path for exactly this effect actually.

You can change your path (at the risk of anything else installed into `/usr/local`) or you could look into removing the manually installed python and using the new [CentOS SCL](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL?highlight=%28SCL%29) for python 2.7.

Comment: What is best way to keep python2.6 intact as default and also install python2.7 ?

Comment: @user3579198 The SCL I would think as that is the only official way to do that and should, I imagine, install python 2.7 as /usr/bin/python2.7 or somesuch non-colliding name.

Comment: python 2.7 is installed as /usr/local/bin/python2.7 & python2.6 is installed as /usr/bin/python2.6

Comment: Yes, that much you made clear. I was talking about what the `SCL` will likely do (and how that is therefor different than what you did).